# how to clone content of a div to another div

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html, copy, clone

I want to copy the content of a selected div to another div with jquery clone.
but I dont want to append it anywhere

what I mean is when we make a clone of a div with jquery (correct me if i am wrong) we have to set its position and it will dynamically create a new division which is displayed.

but I want to get the content of a selected div and copy it to another pre-set div

Comment: thank u all here is what i really want to happen http://www.jsfiddle.net/pahnin/c2p54/2/

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
var a = $('#selector').html();
var b = $('#selector').html(a);
```

not sure I understood you properly but I think thats what you meant :)

Comment: This could also be written: `$('#selectorDestination').html($('#selectorSource').html());`. Avoiding declaring variables.

Comment: Only thing we should be cautious is we shouldn't dupliate the ids in the html

Comment: @dustin yes thats the same thing but i thought since he asked not to put on the dom "i don't want to append it anywhere" :) thats the best way forward

Comment: This approach requires a html parse, the clone/appendTo approach does not. Consider code injection and performance.

Answer (score 12):

I don't agree. Clone can save data without applying to the content.

Look here:

http://www.jsfiddle.net/dactivo/FqffM/

```
var mylayer=$('.hello').clone();
```

Here you can manage the variable "mylayer"  as you want, and it's not in the DOM.

Comment: Of course, html() is a great method but it's good to know that clone() can be managed without including in the DOM

Comment: `Clone` also copies the container element, which I do not think the @pahnin wants.

Comment: Ok, I thought the real problem was you didn't want to set its position. html() is great for this.

Answer (score 9):

```
$("#from").clone().appendTo($("#to"));
```

But it will not remove/hide the main DIV. To hide the main div, do this:

```
$("#from").clone().appendTo($("#to"));
$("#from").remove();
```

Comment: I think you didnt understand my question.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(".from").click(function () {
     $(".from").removeClass("CloneMe");
     $("#to").html('');
     $(this).addClass("CloneMe");
     $(".CloneMe").clone().appendTo("#to");

});
```

You can add a class on click (or other event) that is the hard coded to clone. In this example there is a list of same class names containing styled content (divs etc) -  add the .CloneMe class but first remove that class  to empty the div in case the user selects a different item. )to be safe remove any html as well. Then apply the class using (this) to avoid grabbing all of the items with that class name and finally append to the div. The result is the user can select any item with that class name and populate it in the container. - I imagine using a class for the container would allow you to populate it in more than one place.

---