# Autocomplete on dynamic search field jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am trying to implement `autocomplete` functionality on dynamically generated fields using jquery, but when i am cloning new div the `autocomplete` is not working on newly dynamic generated field

Below is my code:
(autocomplete JQUERY)

```
$(function() {
$(".auto:last")
    // .find("input[class='auto']:last")
    .autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            console.log(request);
            $.ajax({
                url: "searchajax",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    term: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $("#search_text").val(ui.item.value);
            $(".other-fields").show();
        }
    });
});
```

(Clone DIV)

```
var labelCount = 1;
function cloneDiv() {

var $clone = $(".duplicate-vessel:last").clone();
$clone
    .find("input:text")
    .val("")
    .end()
    .each(function() {
        $(this).attr({
            // class: $(this).attr("class") + countAddMore
        });
    });
labelCount++;

$clone.find(".vessel-heading").text("Vessel Info " + labelCount + ":");
$(".form-group").append($clone);

$(".duplicate-vessel:last .cleanVal").val("");
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt. You clone autocomplete value or some other values?

Comment: Refer this site https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002671/how-to-clone-content-of-a-div-to-another-div

Comment: @LooryCS i m cloning autocomplete values.